# Add many objects types in the same column at TreeTable

Tags: java, primefaces, treetable

I have a problem to add many objects types in the same column in TreeTable. The method to create the TreeNodes is in below:

```
TreeNode taskProject = new DefaultTreeNode("node",projet,root);
for (Tache ta : listTache) {
     tache = ta;
     TreeNode taskNode = new DefaultTreeNode("node", tache, taskProject);   

     for (Activite ac : listActivite) {
        activite = ac;
        Tache tac = ac.getTache();
        if (tac.getId() != ta.getId()) {continue;}
        TreeNode taskActivite = new DefaultTreeNode("node",activite,taskNode);
          for (Phase ph : listPhases){
               phase = ph;
              Activite act = ph.getActivite();
              if (act.getId() != ac.getId()) {continue;}
              TreeNode taskPhase = new DefaultTreeNode("leaf",phase,taskActivite);
          }
       }
    }
```

After that, I tried to call the The object in the Treetable and it's work, but don't work when I tried to add these objects in the column. The part of code is in below:

```
<p:treeTable id="treeTable" liveResize="true"
    value="#{projetMediatorController.root}" var="projetMediator">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.projet}" />
    </f:facet>

    <!-- column for the task/activities/phases -->
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.name}" />
        </f:facet>
        <!-- problem -->
        <h:outputText value="#{projetMediatorController.projet.nomProjet}" />
        <!-- <h:outputText value="#{projetMediatorController.tache.nomTache}"/> -->
        <!--<h:outputText value="#{projetMediatorController.activite.nomActivite}"/>-->
        <!--<h:outputText value="#{projetMediatorController.phase.phase}"/>-->
    </p:column>
</p:treeTable>
```

And the problem is to list the objects names on the column "Name" respecting the hierarchy's nodes.

Someone know how can I do that ?

I'm glad for your attention.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this my question with this code:

```
root = new DefaultTreeNode("root", null);
TreeNode projetNode = new DefaultTreeNode("node", new Document(projet), root);

        for (Tache ta : taches) {
            TreeNode tacheNode = new DefaultTreeNode("node", new Document(ta), projetNode);   
            for (Activite ac : activites) {
                Tache tache = ac.getTache();
                if (tache.getId() != ta.getId()) { continue;}
                TreeNode activiteNode = new DefaultTreeNode("node", new Document(ac), tacheNode);

                for (Phase ph : phases) {
                    Activite activite = ph.getActivite();
                    if (activite.getId() != ac.getId()) {continue;}
                    TreeNode phaseNode = new DefaultTreeNode("leaf", new Document(ph), activiteNode);
                }
            }
        }
```

And I was write the Document constructor like this:

```
public class Document implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Projet projet;
    private Tache tache;
    private Activite activite;
    private Phase phase;
    private String nameProjet;

    public Document(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Phase) {
            phase = (Phase)obj;
        }else if (obj instanceof Activite) {
            activite = (Activite)obj;
        }else if (obj instanceof Tache) {
            tache = (Tache)obj;
        }else{
            projet = (Projet)obj;
        }
    }

//gets and sets
}
```

And to finish, the xhtml code to renderer each "objects" rows :

```
<p:treeTable id="treeTable" value="#{documentsController.root}"
                var="document" selection="#{documentsController.selectedNode}" selectionMode="single" resizableColumns="true">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.update} #{bundle.projet}" />
                </f:facet>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.name}" />
                    </f:facet>
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{document.projet.nomProjet}" rendered="#{document.projet == null}"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{document.tache.nomTache}" renderer="#{document.tache == null}" />
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{document.activite.nomActivite}" rendered="#{document.activite == null}"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{document.phase.nomPhase}" rendered="#{document.phase == null}"/>
                </p:column>

                </p:treeTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to construct special class wrapper for node data objects.
Use your class instances directly in TreeNode instead of Document object.
In xhtml use **rendered** attribute on **<p:treeNode>** elements.

[simmilar thread with this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40423301/3158918)