# How to display Parent and Child ( two different objects ) in treetable primefaces?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-extensions

I am using Treetable component to display parent and child objects. I can able to display the parent content by using [this tutorial.](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeTable.jsf)

In my case, I am using two different objects to display the contents in the TreeTable component. Those objects are following.

> 1. **University Detail** - It is my parent Object. It contains (Id and Name of each university) as well as child colleges.
> 2. **College Detail** - It is my child Object. It contains (Id and Name) of each college.

---

**UniversityDetail Class**

```
public class UniversityDetail implements Serializable {

    /**
     * serialVersionUID -   
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /**
     * UniversityId -   
     */
    private Integer UniversityId;
    /**
     * UniversityName   -   
     */
    private String UniversityName;
    /**
     * CollegeDetail    -
     */
    private List<CollegeDetail> CollegeDetail   =   new ArrayList<CollegeDetail>();

    public Integer getUniversityId() {
        return UniversityId;
    }

    public void setUniversityId(Integer UniversityId) {
        this.UniversityId = UniversityId;
    }

    public String getUniversityName() {
        return UniversityName;
    }

    public void setUniversityName(String UniversityName) {
        this.UniversityName = UniversityName;
    }

    public List<CollegeDetail> getCollegeDetail() {
        return CollegeDetail;
    }

    public void setCollegeDetail(
            List<CollegeDetail> collegeDetail) {
        this.CollegeDetail = collegeDetail;
    }

}
```

**College Detail**

```
public class CollegeDetail implements Serializable{

    /**
     * CollegeId    -   
     */
    private Integer CollegeId;
    /**
     * CollegeName  -
     */
    private String CollegeName;

    public Integer getCollegeId() {
        return CollegeId;
    }

    public void setCollegeId(Integer CollegeId) {
        this.CollegeId = CollegeId;
    }

    public String getCollegeName() {
        return CollegeName;
    }

    public void setCollegeName(String CollegeName) {
        this.CollegeName = CollegeName;
    }

}
```

---

**How to display these detail classes with the treetable component ? I dont know how to iterate the child elements(College Detail)**

I have the following xhtml code to display the parent and child. I could render the parent detail. But I am failing to render the child class detail. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<p:treeTable value="#{ManagedBean.root}" var="object" id="multiSelect"  
             selection="#{ManagedBean.selectedNodes}" selectionMode="checkbox">  

    <f:facet name="header">  
        College Dropdown  
    </f:facet>  

    <p:column style="width:100px">  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            University Name  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{object.universityName}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column style="display:none">  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            University ID
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{object.universityId}" />  
    </p:column>  

</p:treeTable>
```

---

**ManagedBean**

```
RootTree = new CheckboxTreeNode("Root", null);
for(int i =0 ; i<CompanyDetail.size();i++) {
UniversityDetail universityDetail   = UniversityDetail.get(i);
    List<CollegeDetail> collegeDetail   =   universityDetail.getCollegeDetail();
    TreeNode parent = new CheckboxTreeNode(universityDetail,RootTree);
    for(int j=0; j<collegeDetail.size();j++) {
    TreeNode child = new CheckboxTreeNode(collegeDetail.get(j).getCollegeName(),collegeDetail.get(j), parent);                  
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `XHTML` page is different form back bean.
But in your case you can make another Class which have only those properties which is needs to be display. and use that class to be display on `XHTML` pages.
lets us know if not work.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Actually it was my typo error. Now updated my question. Please check it out.

Comment: it is easy to display more than one class into tree table as parent-child relation. i have done same thing in my project. but i faced more issue while updated the row table. that why i am suggesting you to use a common class for displaying data.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

**ManagedBean tree getter:**

```
private TreeNode tree;

public TreeNode getTree() {
    if (tree == null) {

        tree = new CheckboxTreeNode("root", null);

        for (UniversityDetail u : universityDetailList) {
            TreeNode uNode = new CheckboxTreeNode("university" ,u ,tree);
            for (CollegeDetail c : u.getCollegeDetail()) {
                TreeNode cNode = new CheckboxTreeNode("collage" ,c ,uNode);
            }
        }
    }

    return tree;

}
```

**xhtml:**

```
<p:treeTable value="#{ManagedBean.tree}" var="object" nodeVar="node" id="multiSelect"  
             selection="#{ManagedBean.selectedNodes}" selectionMode="checkbox">  

    <f:facet name="header">  
        College Dropdown  
    </f:facet>  

    <p:column> 

        <p:treeNode type="university" rendered="#{node.type == 'university'}">
            <h:outputText value="#{object.universityName}" />
        </p:treeNode>

        <p:treeNode type="college" rendered="#{node.type == 'college'}">
            <h:outputText value="#{object.collegeName}" />
        </p:treeNode>

    </p:column>  

    <p:column> 

        <p:treeNode type="university" rendered="#{node.type == 'university'}">
            <h:outputText value="#{object.universityId}" />
        </p:treeNode>

        <p:treeNode type="college" rendered="#{node.type == 'college'}">
            <h:outputText value="#{object.collegeId}" />
        </p:treeNode>

    </p:column>  

</p:treeTable>
```

Tip: use rendered atribute with **node type**:

```
rendered="#{node.type == 'university'}"
```